# RTL languages: comma-separated lists

Tags: javascript, internationalization

I'm using the [ICU Message Format](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/messages) for i18n in an application.

Some of the strings involve dynamic-length comma separated lists. For instance, the string:

> "There are three pets: a dog, a fish, a cat."

may be generated with this message:

> "There are {count} pets: {list}"

Where count is the length of the list, and list are the individual strings themselves. (As an aside, were this a real string I'd be configuring "pets" per "count," but let's keep it simple).

In pseudocode, the list variable might be generated like so:

`pets.join(', ');`

That last bit is what I'm not a fan of. It seems to only make sense for LTR languages, and possibly just a subset of LTR languages.

I have two questions:

1. How should comma-separated lists be formatted in other languages, such as RTL languages?
2. Does the ICU Message Format support that in any way, or does it require a system in addition to ICU to generate the lists?

For what it's worth, this is a JavaScript webapp, although the answers to these questions are probably language-agnostic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

List formatting is locale sensitive. Not all languages use the "ASCII comma", or spaces.
ICU has a ListFormatter:
http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/text/ListFormatter.html

For JavaScript Closure has an equivalent
https://github.com/google/closure-library/blob/master/closure/goog/labs/i18n/listformat.js

---

**July 2019 update**

There is (finally) support for list formatting in ECMAScript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ListFormat

It is (still) not well supported, but give it some time

Comment: Thanks @MihaiNita!  I ended up doing some research and implemented a thing that works for my use cases for now: https://github.com/jmeas/i18n-list-generator.js I'm going to take a look at these other options and see if I can improve my code or otherwise just use their libs instead. Thanks again :)

Comment: At least take a look at the data in closure and copy some more data in your hardcoded solution. There are other languages that don't use "the ASCII comma" (for instance Chinese). See listsymbols.js and listsymbolsext.js in https://github.com/google/closure-library/tree/master/closure/goog/labs/i18n

Comment: Thanks once more! I will do that.

Comment: Is there any JavaScript implementation that isn't dependent on the Google Closure library?